# Vertical centring with :after pseudo-element not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically centre my `introWrap` container using the `:after` pseudo-element method (as described at the end of [this article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)). I've always applied this method without any problems, but I can't for my life seem to understand why it doesn't work in this case (http://jsfiddle.net/4yfru/2/).

Right now the `introWrap` div is at the top, whilst it should really be in the center on the vertical axis. I tried replacing the `:after` pseudo-element with a `span`, and it worked perfectly. Something's fishy is going on here and I don't know what.

Could any kind soul please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong element with the `:after` applied. You need to apply it to the "wrapping" element, so [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/4yfru/5/):

```
#intro:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You, my friend, are God. However, it still doesn't make sense to me. I've always done applied ``:after`` on the element being wrapped, so I'm wondering why it is not working in this case. :/

Comment: Oh no! Please don't (even in jest) refer to me as "God," a title which only belongs to Jesus Christ my Savior. In answer to "why," I can only say "I don't know" (see, I'm not God). The technique listed on the site you reference clearly says, "a 'ghost' element inside the parent," which would indicate it does not work inside the child. You mention a span replacement working, but I do not see that [on the child](http://jsfiddle.net/4yfru/6/), only if [in the parent](http://jsfiddle.net/4yfru/7/). So if it did work for you previously, I don't know why.

Comment: You are welcome. I was not offended, though maybe God was. Glad you have it working, however.